# CSS Outside Border

Tags: css, border

I want to be able to draw a border OUTSIDE of my Div! So if my div is say 20px by 20px, I want a 1px border outside of this (so in essence, I get a div 22x22px large).

I understand that I can just make the div 22x22 to start with, but for reasons I have, I need the borders to be on the outside.

CSS outline works, but I want only border-bottom or border-top thingy, so something like outline-bottom, which does not work, is what I want.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Start reading: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

Comment: This is especially useful when you have a dashed or transparent border and you don't want to see the background of the `<div>` behind it, but the background of the parent container. Just use the `outline` property instead of `border`.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

I think you've got your understanding of the two properties off a little.  Border affects the outside edge of the element, making the element different in size. Outline will not change the size or position of the element (takes up no space) and goes outside the border.  From your description you want to use the border property.

Look at the simple example below in your browser:

```html
<div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: black; color: white; outline: thick solid #00ff00">SOME TEXT HERE</div>

<div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: black; color: white; border-left: thick solid #00ff00">SOME TEXT HERE</div>
```

Notice how the border pushes the bottom div over, but the outline doesn't move the top div and the outline actually overlaps the bottom div.

You can read more about it here:
[Border](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border.asp)
[Outline](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline.asp)

Comment: not dead, just wrong, take out the quoted word from the address bar

Answer (score 30):

Try the outline property [CSS Outline](http://codepen.io/bengoddard/pen/Ejatx/)

Outline will not interfere with widths and lengths of the elements/divs!

Please click the link I provided at the bottom to *see working demos* of the the different ways you can make borders, and inner/inline borders, even ones that do not disrupt the dimensions of the element! No need to add extra divs every time, as mentioned in another answer!

You can also combine borders with outlines, and if you like, box-shadows (also shown via link)

```
<head>
   <style type="text/css" ref="stylesheet">
      div {
        width:22px;
        height:22px;
        outline:1px solid black;
      }
   </style>
</head>
<div>
    outlined
</div>
```

Usually by default, 'border:' puts the border on the outside of the width, measurement, adding to the overall dimensions, unless you use the 'inset' value:

```
div {border: inset solid 1px black};
```

But 'outline:' is an extra border outside of the border, and of course still adds extra width/length to the element.

**PS: I also was inspired to make this for you**: [Using borders, outlines, and box-shadows](http://codepen.io/bengoddard/pen/Ejatx/)

Comment: Outline is an accessibility feature, and hijacking it this way might not be the best way. It's meant to be used to highlight the active element for someone who has visual impairment.

Comment: a box shadow without blur like `box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;` is an excellent solution for outlines not working with border radius on Safari (they are square instead of rounded). This is a pretty common problem that looks like it will be fixed in 16.4 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-16_4-release-notes . Other solutions I've seen can be rather messy https://medium.com/@jeandesravines/use-border-radius-and-outline-simultaneously-on-safari-14ce92889e1f

Answer (score 16):

IsisCode gives you a good solution. Another one is to position border div *inside* parent div. Check this example http://jsfiddle.net/A2tu9/

**UPD:** You can also use pseudo element `:after` (`:before`), in this case HTML will not be polluted with extra markup:

```
.my-div {
    position: relative;
    padding: 4px;
    ...
}
.my-div:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    left: -3px;
    bottom: -3px;
    right: -3px;
    border: 1px #888 solid;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/A2tu9/191/

Comment: If one wants to catch clicks with a handler on `.my-div` add `pointer-events:none;` onto `.my-div:after`

Answer (score 14):

Why not simply using `background-clip`?

```
-webkit-background-clip: padding;
   -moz-background-clip: padding;
        background-clip: padding-box;
```

See:
http://caniuse.com/#search=background-clip
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-clip

Answer (score 11):

I shared two solutions depending on your needs:

```html
<style type="text/css" ref="stylesheet">
  .border-inside-box {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .border-inside-box-v1 {
    outline: 1px solid black; /* 'border-radius' not available */
  }
  .border-outside-box-v2 {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black; /* 'border-style' not available (dashed, solid, etc) */
  }
</style>
```

example: https://codepen.io/danieldd/pen/gObEYKj

Comment: Great use of `box-shadow`! For bottom line: `box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 black;`

Answer (score 10):

Way late, but I just ran into a similar issue.
My solution was pseudo elements - no additional markup, and you get to draw the border without affecting the width.
Position the pseudo element absolutely (with the main positioned relatively) and whammo.

See below, [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/mcx6m/).

```css
.hello {
    position: relative;
    /* Styling not important */
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.hello::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: -5px;
    right: -5px;
    bottom: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid red;
    border-right: 5px solid red;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Put your div inside another div, apply the border to the outer div with *n* amount of padding/margin where *n* is the space you want between them.

Answer (score 1):

try adding

```
box-sizing: content-box;
```

(instead of `box-sizing: border-box;`)