# Color Outer Boundaries by css for a map Region

Tags: html, css

Is there any possibly to colour regions differently on Map by css?. I am not able to find relevant post

I have I map portion like this :

[image]

This region contain five sub regions as you can see .Every Subregion Boundary is Red .I need to make only outer Boundary(Touching the sea)is Black

here is the relavant code :

For Outer Region

```
            mapdata.parentId = "c0";

            mapdata.name = a;
            mapdata.title = "Arron";
            mapdata.cName = "_21";            **<--Class Name**  
            mapdata.zoom = 0;
            mapdata.backUrl = "?v=arron&d=" + d;

            //get all arrondisments
            using (var query = new SiteAdminQuery())
            {
                DrawSingleArrondissment(a, query, paths);

                if (showCity)
                {
                    DrawAllCitiesForSelectedArrondissment(d, a, query, paths, false, true);
                }
            }

                mapdata.paths = paths.OrderByDescending(x => x.BoundaryDisplayOrder).ToArray();
            }
```

For Inner Region:

```
  key = arrondissementSetUp.arrndsId.ToString(),
                    type = "a",
                    mType = string.Format("{0}: {1}", HEM.Resources.Globals.arrnds, arrondissementSetUp.name),
                    url = string.Format("?v={0}&d={1}&a={2}", "arron", arrondissementSetUp.deptId, arrondissementSetUp.arrndsId),

                   cName = "_New21",      **<--Class Name**

                    path = arrondissementSetUp.mainViewPathId.ToString(),
                    BoundaryDisplayOrder=3
```

this is the css for Regions :

```
._21 {
    fill: #ffff7d;
     stroke: #000000;
    stroke-width: 1;
}

  .New_21{
    fill: #ffff7d;
     stroke: #d10909;
    stroke-width: 1;
}
```

I tried to use .class:After Property , but this is not working .

I found example in this post

[CSS Outside Border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102900/css-outside-border)

http://jsfiddle.net/A2tu9/191/ .

I search google with keywords like

"css :set outer Boundary/Border color","css :set inner boundary/Border", and like that ..
but not able to find any good Post . The regions are created with map Coordinates , So i cant able to post entire Code ..

Let me know If any other resource is required . I will post it

Please also suggest if this thing can happen with any other techniques

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like your provinces are drawn out by SVG. There's not a single property that's going to do what you need it to do. What you need to do instead is AFTER you draw out the individual regions, you need to draw out the whole island again as a single SVG element (i.e. one solid shape that is the shape of the whole island, ignoring the individual regions), and set `fill: transparent; stroke:black;`

Because you're drawing it after, it'll sit on top of the existing island, and the black border will just cover the outside red one.

Comment: I did this , but when  do mouse hover , it Hover of outer region , which is wrong , I need to hover for smaller region

Comment: You didn't say in your post that you had to hover over everything, so you'll have to excuse the lack of clarity. However, the solution is simple: in the DOM, move the provinces lower in the DOM than the outline. i.e.:

<path for whole region>
<path for sub-region>
<path for sub-region>

Comment: ok , I missed that , But as per your solution , Moving in the elements in DOM is a temporary fix , isnt it ?

Comment: The other option would be to set the CSS property on the whole region to pointer-events:none