# CSS circles - outer border with white space on inside of element

Tags: html, css

I want a circular border around a circle that has white space on the inside of it.

This is what I tried:

```css
.status {
    display: block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #2ed091;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<span class="status"></span>
```

As you can see, the black is touching the green - they should NOT be touching.

I then researched and found [CSS Outside Border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102900/css-outside-border)

```css
.status {
    display: block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #2ed091;
    padding: 15px;
    outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<span class="status"></span>
```

But it comes out as a box and the border radius doesn't apply. Why?

I then found another answer that suggested pseudo elements

```css
.status {
    display: block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #2ed091;
    padding: 15px;
}

.status:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  width: 87px;
  height: 87px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<span class="status"></span>
```

Which does look the closest, but I can't get it circular and aligned with the circle.

How do I add a circle around another circle with whitespace inside of it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use   `background-clip: content-box;` so your background fills the content area only and set `padding` as a size of white space.

See the snippet below:

```css
.status {
  display: block;
  width: 8em;
  height: 8em;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #2ed091;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  background-clip: content-box;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<span class="status"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think @KoshVery's answer is much more straight-forward and therefore preferable in most scenarios.

Just in case you'd like to modify the colour of the white part of the border, I can offer another solution:

```css
.status {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #2ed091;
}

.status:before {
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid white;
  background-color: #2ed091;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<span class="status"></span>
```